# Package revision after probation

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, compensation

I am near a probation end period and in my documents, I couldn't find anything that says anything about a raise or revised salaries.

How can I ask or put a request for a revision of my package whilst meeting after probation, as my peer has a impression on the PM that he knows best and he trusts him, and might convince my manager, about work I do and compare with his. Whereas I was hired to overcome problems for the company, which I did.

Will it harm my image or will my company will look somewhere else for a different person? In the end a UX guy is always told "your work is simple and you are overpaid or maybe you're at best spot in the market". How can I ask without making myself look bad or greedy?

Comment: [Relevant](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: @Draken not really, i am still almost at the end of probation and i never saw or thought of point of raise in my contract. Whereas the question you related to is 2 yrs of working and it was non-negotiable.

Comment: Hence why I didn't mark it as a duplicate, however if you read the [first answer given](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1026/52713), it gives you a lot of tips that are relevant for negotiating a better salary. Have a read, learn and see what you can apply to your current job for asking for a better wage

Comment: @Draken thanks, that answer was helpful. I will edit my question too now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I'll cover the edits in the question, but the below still is relevant to the question

Ignore the stuff about your peer. Your manager will not discuss your salary etc with your peer. If you are delivering things for the project, the PM will know and appreciate that. It sounds like there are maybe more issues than renumeration here though, it sounds like there may be friction between you and your peer and is that the real issue? I wouldn't worry if you decided to go elsewhere. If the job isn't a good fit for you then it happens. As long as you don't leave lots of jobs during probation then it isn't an issue.

The original answer below still stands though, it would be a tough sell to get a pay rise after probation period based on commute (when that should have been considered before accepting the job offer).

Original Answer:

I can't personally see how you can justify asking for more based on the commute when you knew there would be a long commute when you took the job and agreed with the salary on offer. I assumed you signed a contract agreeing to the renumeration too.

The probationary period is a time where both employer and employee see if the role is a good fit. It's usually not enough time to then ask for a pay rise and isn't really designed for this in the industry (I get that call centres etc sometimes use this as a carrot to retain staff).

If you take the role permanently now you can then look at your Performance/Pay Review policies and follow those in 6-12 months (company dependant).

Could you cut down on the self training? Or use cheaper alternatives (i.e. Use PluralSight etc rather than face to face courses if you do this?).

Comment: I have edited the question, it is more of my peer who is backend is trying to prove that UX job is easy and trying to learn things by experimenting and leaving bad bad code, i been in couple of meeting to find out what he think and he think "bad code" is a problem, but for me it is and manager seem to take his word as he believes in end product being delivered on time, The missing things 1). I don't have nature of fight or argue which lead other person to believe i am weak in my argument and might be running away 2)it was my mistake not have asked for when is performance/pay review while sign

Comment: I haven't got a email or meeting invite from my boss to review my probation, should i ask him as i signed contract 2 weeks before joining, so don't know when the probation end.